# reCAPTCHA placeholder errors as no captcha on page

Tags: javascript, google-api, recaptcha

I keep getting same error, I believe its because this form has no captcha as its not needed on this one page. Is there a way to solve this error ?

I have tried to inject a id if there is non present but this dose not seem to work

```
recaptcha__en.js:496 Uncaught Error: reCAPTCHA placeholder element must be an element or id
at Object.dF [as render] (recaptcha__en.js:496)
at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> ((index):973)
at Function.each (jquery.js:365)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:137)
at loadCaptcha ((index):970)
at BK (recaptcha__en.js:501)
at qY (recaptcha__en.js:491)
at recaptcha__en.js:504
at recaptcha__en.js:524
```

Comment: I guess what the error is trying to say is, that reCAPTCHA needs some sort of a container to render itself. But it's not present in your template.

Comment: @SiddAjmera yep thats what i get, however is there a way in the javascript to alter it so that if no container run anyways